# Incorrect sections in UITableView when using FetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've come across an issue that isn't making any sense to me:

I have a table view which displays objects ordered by the date they were created. The objects in the table view are grouped by a `dateString` property (e.g. "March 2017"). I had this working perfectly, but I've been simplifying my Core Data stack, and when I use a different instance of `NSManagedObjectContext` for the `FetchedResultsController` instance which controls my table view, the section ordering breaks. The fetch still returns the objects in the correct descending order, but the sections do not pertain to the objects they contain, and, to make things slightly more confusing, are themselves ordered alphabetically.

Here's how the controller is configured:

```
let context = Database.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Entry")
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateCreated", ascending: false)

request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
request.fetchBatchSize = 1000
    
FRC = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request,
                         managedObjectContext: context,
                           sectionNameKeyPath: "dateString",
                                    cacheName: nil)
```

And here are the **incorrect** sections from the `FetchedResultsController` (looped over them and printed):

```
OCTOBER 2018, NOVEMBER 2020, NOVEMBER 2018, MAY 2019, MAY 2016, MARCH 2019, JUNE 2019, JULY 2017, JANUARY 2021, JANUARY 2019, JANUARY 2017, DECEMBER 2020, DECEMBER 2017, DECEMBER 2016, AUGUST 2019, AUGUST 2018, APRIL 2019
```

Simply changing the `NSManagedObjectContext` instance for `FRC` to how it was before results in the correct ordering:

```
JANUARY 2021, DECEMBER 2020, NOVEMBER 2020, AUGUST 2019, JUNE 2019, MAY 2019, APRIL 2019, MARCH 2019, JANUARY 2019, NOVEMBER 2018, OCTOBER 2018, AUGUST 2018, DECEMBER 2017, JULY 2017, JANUARY 2017, DECEMBER 2016, MAY 2016
```

Any clues on this? It's not making any sense to me.

Comment: I would be interested to see the output from SQLDebug from the two separate FRCs.  Also, how are the two managed object contexts related?

Comment: I performed a test where I delete the app and have it refetch all the data from CloudKit to see how the sections turn out. When I fetch from scratch, the sections are correct. As soon as I quit the app and relaunch, they go back to being incorrect. Is it possible that this is a bug on Apple's end?

Comment: Out of interest, does the behaviour change if you remove the fetchBatchSize?

Comment: My guess is that the different behaviour relates to whether the data is in memory or in the backing store.  Using SQLDebug might give some clues as to whether that is the case.  As a fix, I suggest changing your dateString to yyyy-MM format, because this will give the correct order for the sections when it is sorted alphabetically.  You can then change the format to MMMM yyyy for display purposes.

Comment: Behavior doesn't change with the batch size :/. When I'm using the `viewContext` provided by the persistent container, I get incorrect sections. If, however, I simply create a new `NSManagedObjectContext` that works on the main thread, and set its parent to `viewContext`, and then use that new context for `FRC`, the sections are correct. Not really sure why this would happen as I assume that when a context fetches, it's doing so through its parent.